# alert box is not working in javascript while validating html form in JAVAFX

Tags: javascript, html, javafx

i am pretty much new to javafx. i have built an application on javafx which will load index.html  page through WebView. when i click on register button in index.html new registration form page will be loaded.

**javafx code:**

```
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    FrontEndFinal f=new FrontEndFinal();

    final WebView browser = new WebView();
    final WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();
    webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    Worker<Void> worker = webEngine.getLoadWorker();
    worker.stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<State>() {

        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends State> observable, //
                State oldValue, State newValue) {

            // When load successed.
            if (newValue == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {

                JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");

                jsobj.setMember("myJavaMember", new FrontEndFinal());
            }
        }
    });
    VBox root = new VBox();

    root.setMinHeight(500);
    root.setMinWidth(1250);


    System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    String p=System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String [] t=p.split("\\\\");
    System.out.println(t.length);
    String final1=t[0]+"/";
    for(int i=1;i<t.length;i++)
    {
        final1=final1+t[i]+"/";
    }
    System.out.println(final1);


    browser.getEngine().load("file:///"+final1+"/Html"+"/SMS.html");
    root.getChildren().add(browser); 
}
```

When I run this code it loads `index.html`

**in Index.html:**

```
<button class="dropbtn"  onclick="location.href = 'Registration.html'"><b>< Register ></b></button>
```

after clicking button it opens `Registration.html`

**In Registration.html**

```
<form name="myForm"  method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<button type="button" name="Submit" onclick="abc()">Submit</button>
<script>
function abc(){
    window.alert("Invalid name");
}
```

**Now** my problem is when i submit Registration.html form with name field blank, it does not shows alert box
i googled many sites like:[https://community.oracle.com/thread/2540279]
 but didn't work
Any help or suggestions?

**Thanks In Advance**

Answer (score 2):

You need to set an `onAlert` handler on the web engine. This gives you the ability to configure how you want your application to respond to Javascript `alert()` callbacks. To show a simple dialog message:

```
webEngine.setOnAlert(event -> {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setContentText(event.getData());
    alert.showAndWait();
});
```

Here is a SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WebViewAlertTest extends Application {

    private final String HTML = ""
            + "<html>"
            + "<body>"
            + "<button onclick='alert(\"Javascript Alert\")'>Submit</button>"
            + "</body>"
            + "</html>";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();
        webEngine.setOnAlert(event -> {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setHeaderText("Message from the web page");
            alert.setContentText(event.getData());
            alert.showAndWait();
        });
        webEngine.loadContent(HTML);

        Scene scene = new Scene(webView, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @James_D Thanks for you reply...but when i run above code it shows error saying event cannot be resolved to a variable.

Comment: @sagnemsagnem The code works fine. I added a complete example that you can run.